# If two standard normal distributions X,Y has correlation 1, are they the same random variable?

Tags: random-variables

Maybe I am silly. Are these two random variables the same? Would there be any situation that they are not?

Comment: Yes. That follows from condition for equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!